# Is it right to say that "git clone" creates a new repository?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have been learning **git** and kind of stuck on the topic "Create a new Repository".

I get that `git clone` copies an existing repository to your PC.

Is it right to say that `git clone` creates a new repository on your PC?

Thanks

Comment: It does created a new repository in the sense that it creates a totally new one, if you have worked with SVN before you might want to check out this documentation for proper understanding. 

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/git-clone


" Unlike SVN, Git makes no distinction between the working copy and the central repository—they are all full-fledged Git repositories."

Comment: Can that repository on my PC be `git clone` by any other PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, so long as you keep the specification that it's a new repository *on your PC.*

Comment: Can that repository on my PC be `git clone` by any other PC?

Comment: Yes, once you have made it available to them by pushing to a server or service like Github or BitBucket.

Comment: If this answered your question, can you accept the answer? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it creates new repo to your machine where you run the command.

Comment: Can that repository on my PC be `git clone` by any other PC?

Comment: Do you mean to clone your pc's repository to other pc?

Comment: yes. If I create a new repository on my PC using `git clone` then can a new repository be created on some other PC by using `git clone` and referring to my PC?

Comment: Yes that's the interesting part. Anyone who have git install in there pc can clone this repository. Because every pc or machine in git is a individual server.